# AWS Hosting - DNS Records

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, spam, dkim

I cannot send emails from our company domain anymore. It directly sends the messages to the spam folders. I was told that some of the DNS records might be blacklisted so it can cause the issue of emails being marked as spam. I was recommended to talk to someone from AWS and see why those records are there and to remove them if they are not linked to a website and if they are to generate new ones, records that are not blacklisted at least. It was not possible to talk to anyone on AWS. I was wondering if anyone had the same issue and recommend me how I can know which records should I remove or keep to continue emailing in peace again!

Thanks:)

Comment: why was it not possible to talk to AWS, did you open a support ticket?

Comment: they do not allow to open a ticket or seek support for technical issues unless I upgrade my plan